What is the procedure for replacing the fork?
I'd like to replace the fork on my Huffy 26 inch Scout Mens 21 Speed Hard Tail MTB. I want to use a better suspension fork, ideally the (insert brand and model, or say in general what type of fork).

Neither [Walmart's][2] nor [Huffy's][3] site have detailed specifications about the head tube diameter. I have the hex wrenches. Removing the disc brake caliper looks pretty straight forward.
What things should I watch out for, e.g.

Do I need tools other than hex wrenches?
What should I look out for in a new fork to be compatible with my head tube?
Are there compatibility issues I have missed?


Your question lacks details. What bike it is? What type of steerer (carbon/alu)? What headset do you have (threaded/threadless)? What new fork are you getting? The answer to your question depends on all of the above and then some.

This is not trivial, a lot (And I mean a lot...) of pitfalls, and your gonna need more 'wrenches'. Main thing is replacement fork has match not so easy these days.. steerer, steerer length (usually needs to be cut down), axle, axle/crown (maintain geometry).  Disk caliper may need a different adapter. Need to install crown nut and headset race (depends on headset used).

@Art Gertner You are assuming I know everything.

@mattnz When you say "It is not trivial" Are you saying you can not help me?

You simply have to provide much more information. If you don't know this information, there is a high risk that the frame and the fork will not fit together. For the start the exact models of the frame and of the fork are needed. The bike looks to be a supermarket one with a threadless headset and mechanical brakes. But the descriptions on the shop websites are incomplete. The types and dimensions of the bearings (races) are important.

I see this has been downvoted twice, but it is quite an easy question to answer, there are not infinate variables. Whether you have everything you need to complete the job is another question but giving an overview is not hard.

@Noise I did not downvote but I did vote to close because there is not enough information. Others voted to close with a different reason, that the question - how to change MTB forks in general - is too broad for this site. I am not sure about that. But to answer how to change the fork specifically on Huffy 26 inch Scout Mens 21 Speed Hard Tail MTB we do not have, IMHO, enough information.

Same here, I did not down vote, but the question shows lack of prior research. The internet is full of 'how to' for anyone willing to look for it. This is a QA site, not a tutorial site, and it must not become one.  "Bicycle Fork Replacement" in google should get the OP started.

I have rolled back the edit, as it did not belong in the question. This is the text that was edited in: "I feel that many are starting off with some assumptions that are not true and are quick to criticize.
Asking some probing questions would be helpful.
I have the answer. I just need the ability to provide it."

@fixit7 please edit useful information about your research or your planned approach into the question.

@fixit7, requests to reopen do not belong in the question. More details about the bike or its parts are an acceptable edit and will lead to reopening. Re-asking the question will lead to a second closed and/or deleted question. Please learn to fit in with the site/network.

I've edited the question. This may make it answerable while preserving the original intent, I think. There are details the OP should fill in. This is the sort of editing we were looking for. I think we aren't so strict about only one question per answer. However, the original question was extremely open-ended. Questions like that don't tend to be well-received. It's just how this site works, and we work differently from online forums.

Note that to unmount and remount the fork, hex wrenches are sufficient (it does look like standard threadless headless). Unmounting the fork will be necessary to get the dimensions of the steerer tube and the headset, so already unmounting the fork (keep track of the sequence for the bearings/spacers) will provide valuable information as well.


Do I need tools other than hex wrenches?

Yes. You need:

A crown race remover to remove the crown race from the old fork
A crown race installer to install the crown race to the new fork
A star nut installation tool to install a star nut to the new fork
A fresh, unused star nut (cheap, buy several just in case) if it has a metal steerer, unsafe to use with carbon steerers
Maybe: a hacksaw or pipe cutter or enough many headset/stem spacers if you don't want to cut the steerer tube

Since you need crown race remover, installer and star nut installer maybe only few times in your life, it may be better to just take the bike and new fork to a bike shop. It's probably cheaper to have a bike shop install the fork than to buy all the needed tools. Some tools may be avoided by improvising but I don't recommend that, there's a high risk of invalid installation.

What should I look out for in a new fork to be compatible with my head tube?


Compatible head tube diameter, usually 1+1/8" straight or 1+1/2" to 1+1/8" tapered
Axle-to-crown distance that doesn't change the bike geometry too much, but since this is a suspension fork, it isn't so exact
Compatible wheel attachment: QR vs thru-axle and if thru-axle what diameter


Are there compatibility issues I have missed?

Yes. Head tube diameter needs to be compatible or else you won't be installing the fork. If axle-to-crown distance differs too much, you can install the fork but it will affect the way the bike feels when riding.
And if you can't attach the old front wheel to the new fork, you need a new wheel so better buy a fork where you can attach the wheel.

I would not say that you need to buy all the tools, there are DIY versions that work if you have more time (which shops don't have). For the crownrace remover, if the headset is standard, buying a new headset is probably a smarter move than buying a remover. When I replaced my fork, I used PVC piping as crown race installer, and the old stem cap as star nut installer tool (the star nut was supplied with the fork, so no need to buy one in advance). The spacers can also be reused.

A new headset may require headset press. However, if the frame has non-press headset, buying a new headset is probably a good idea and avoids needing many of the tools.
